# $\lim_{n \to \infty}n\sin\left(\pi/n\right)$

Tags: limits

Assume unit radius. The area of regular polygon with $n$ sides = $n\sin\left(\pi/n\right)$, how does $n\sin\left(\pi/n\right)$ approach $1$ as $n \to \infty$ ?.

$$
\mbox{I have tried}\quad
\pi\,{\sin\left(\pi/n\right) \over \pi/n}\quad \mbox{so it looks like}\quad \pi\,{\sin(x) \over x}
$$
L'Hopital's Rule and I still can not get
$\quad\lim_{x \to \infty}\sin\left(x\right)/x = 1$.

Comment: If you're considering unit radius then the area of the regular polygon with n sides converges to the area of the circle of radius one, so it converges to $\pi$, which is what you have found. What is the problem?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \color{red}\infty}\sin(\pi/n)] / (\pi/n)=\lim_{x\to\color{red}0+}\sin x / x = 1$

Comment: Of course, I don't know why i could not see that myself. Both x and sin x approaches 0 from positive.  My bad...Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As $\epsilon\to0$, we have $\sin\epsilon=\epsilon+o(\epsilon)$ (it's [Taylor's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) around $0$, at order $1$), hence, as $n\to\infty$,

$$n\sin\frac\pi n=n\left(\frac\pi n+o(\frac1n)\right)=\pi+o(1)\to\pi$$

---

Note about the edit and its rollback

The edit by Nerarith was incorrect and unnecessary: $f(x)=o(g(x))$ iff $f(x)=\epsilon(x) \cdot g(x)$ with $\epsilon(x)\to0$. Not to be confused with $f(x)=O(g(x))$, iff there is a constant $M$ such that $|f(x)|\le M|g(x)|$ (in both cases, it's supposed to hold when $x\to x_0$ or $x\to\infty$).

Here I wrote the minimal information necessary to find the limit. We **could** write $\sin\frac{\pi}{n}=\frac{\pi}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})$, but it's not mandatory. However, we **can't** write $\sin\frac{\pi}{n}=\frac{\pi}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$, as it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For small values of $x$, $\sin x\sim x$. So for large values of $x$, $\sin(1/x)\sim 1/x$. So as $n$ increases, $n\sin(\pi/n) \sim n\cdot\pi/n = \pi$.

Comment: For $n=1000$, my calculator says that $n\sin(\pi/n)\approx3.14159$.

Comment: You forgot a `π` factor.

Answer (score 2):

As often, the shortest is to use *equivalents*:

$\sin x\sim_0 x$, hence $\sin\dfrac\pi n\sim_\infty\dfrac\pi n$ and
$$n\sin\frac\pi n\sim_\infty n\dfrac\pi n=\pi.$$

Comment: I haven't seen this notation or terminology before -- can you provide a reference? It looks like an interesting way to think about these problems which I would like to learn about

Comment: It's a way to remove irrelevant details when calculating limits.  $\sim_a$ reads as ‘equivalent in a neighbourhood of $a$’. You can take a look at the Wikipedia note on [Asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out this can be derived from [Archimedes' Method](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/archimedes-method-for-computing-areas-and-volumes-introduction) for calculating the area of a (unit) circle (here we apply it for a polygon with $2n$ sides)

[image]